# Are S.P.E.C.I.A.L. skills capped at 10?

Tags: fallout-shelter

We know that the maximum level a dweller can train to on any SPECIAL skill is 10, however this does not consider bonuses given from their outfit.

Is there any additional benefit for going over 10? For example, a dweller with an Intelligence skill of 10 wearing a lab coat that boosts Intelligence by 3?

If it is a hard cap, would it be more useful to use outfits that raise a secondary characteristic instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there may be a benefit.

If you drag and drop a person to a room you'll see the stats need for the room and the stats of your person. If you drag a person which has `S:10` to a reactor you'll see `S 10` beside her. If you drag a person with `S:9` and a military outfit (`S+3`) to the reactor room it still displays `S 10`.

Besides that display error, you can still use the higher stats provided by an outfit to reduce the cooldown of a room. If you use a `S 10` in a reactor you still can reduce the cooldown of the room if you give him a military outfit (for example).